# Convert string to date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, date-formatting

I have a string variable I want the variable into date format.

**My Code:**

```
var date = '2/3/2022 17:57:30'
var temp = new Date(date)
```

**My Output:**

```
2022-02-03T17:57:30.000Z
```

**Expected Output**:

```
2022-02-03
```

Comment: you can refer to this document https://stove99.tistory.com/46

Comment: Hi, you can use the other date function to get the day and month and year and concat it with a string.temp will heave other built in date functions like temp.getFullYear() or temp.getMonth() and temp.getDate(). Get those and just convert it to string. make a helper function that will convert date into this format. Hope it helps

Comment: Is that Feb 3 or Mar 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleDateString` with an argument that specifies a locale for which your format is used. For instance, the Swedisch locale uses the YYYY-MM-DD format:

```js
var date = '2/3/2022 17:57:30'
var temp = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("se");
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to convert date into your expected output although you can try this piece of code to convert date into your expected output;

```
var date = '2/3/2022 17:57:30'
var temp = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString().replaceAll("/","-");
```